# factor through k-split map

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra and $ϕ : U → V$ a homomorphism of $A$-modules. If $ϕ$ factors through a relatively $k$-projective $A$-module, then $ϕ$ factors through any $k$-split surjective (i.e. it has a $k$-linear section) $A$-homomorphism $δ : W → V$.

In the proof it is stated "there is a relatively $k$-projective $A$-module $P$ and $A$-homomorphisms
$α : U → P$ and $β : P → V$ such that $ϕ = β ◦ α$. Since $δ$ is $k$-split, it follows that $β$ factors through $δ$ as a $k$-linear map. But then since $P$ is relatively $k$-projective, it follows further that $β$ factors through $δ$ as an A-homomorphism."

These two "it follows" completely lost me. Any hints would be appreciated.